# how can validate phone number with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate the following phone number with regex:

```
1) +415XXXXXXXX
2) 00415XXXXXXXX
3) 41 5XXXXXXXX
4) 41 05XXXXXXXX
5) 05XXXXXXXX
6) 5XXXXXXXX
```

I tries this expression

```
^\+?41?\s?0?5\d{8}$
```

and was able to validate situations (1,3,4), could any one help me to adjust the above one to be able to cover the rest scenarios?

Comment: Your regex seems to only validate phone numbers that begin with "41", which explains why 1, 3, 4 are the only ones that match. I'm not sure what the conditions of your problem are, since you can technically write a regex to accept any string of numbers as "phone numbers".

Comment: Use `^(?:(?:\+|00)415|41 0?5|0?5)\d{8}$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/IDkscC/2))

Comment: that was great, thanks, i didn't know what to use to make the number start with 0041 or +41 :)

Answer (score 0):

One "brute force" approach would be to just handle each prefix separately in an alternation:

```js
var nums = ["+41512345678", "0041512345678", "41 512345678", "41 0512345678", "0512345678", "512345678", "2128675309"];
nums.forEach(function(number) {
    console.log(number + " passes? " +
/^(?:\+415|00415|41 0?5|0?5)\d{8}$/.test(number));
});
```